# How to get access to edit public class CompactCalendarView.java file ? (Android CompactCalendarView library)

Tags: android, view, calendar

So here is the situation. I'm using Android Studio and making calendar app with CompactCalendarView library (https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView), I added `compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.8.3'` to my dependencies and everything works fine. But my problem is that I want to add my code to `public class CompactCalendarView extends View` and I cannot do that, because the file `CompactCalendarView.java`  is locked for me.

I assume that by doing `compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.8.3'` I'm not adding that library from my libraries directory, therefore I have no access to edit it? I tried adding `compile project ('libs:CompactCalendar')` and yes, I have the project on my libraries, also included it in my `settings.gradle` but it gives me an error:

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

So is there any way it is possible to edit CompactCalendarView public class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume that by doing compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.8.3' I'm not adding that library from my libraries directory, therefore I have no access to edit it?

Correct. You are downloading a published packaged edition of that library (in AAR format, most likely) from an artifact repository (JCenter, most likely).

> but it gives me an error

I do not know what exactly you have in `:libs:CompactCalendar`. That should contain the contents of [the GitHub repository's library directory](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView/tree/master/library).

Comment: Nice, thanks, I was importing the whole project in the libs folder. Now I will know to import only library folder. :)

Comment: @Rimvydas: Most of these sorts of projects have a demo app alongside the library. You only need the library portion.